# EASY: vba: Looking through a listbox and selecting the contents

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know this is something really simple and it's slipping my mine right now. how do I loop though a listbox and select the contents?

Here's the code I've made right now:

```
Dim allGrps As Integer
Dim i As Integer
allGrps = lstAllGroups.ListCount
For i = 1 To allGrps
lstAllGroups
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the listbox is zero-indexed so you've got to subtract one off from i:

```
For i = 1 To allGrps
    lstAllGroups.Selected(i - 1) = True
Next i
```

Also, make sure you've got `SelectSheetsList.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti`
 in order to be able to select multiple items in the list.

See [the ListBox documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835338(v=office.15).aspx) for more info.