# How to check values in a listbox and select certain rows

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I found this question...
[EASY: vba: Looking through a listbox and selecting the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682659/easy-vba-looking-through-a-listbox-and-selecting-the-contents)
but it seems to select every item...not very useful.

I need to load a popup form's ListBox with the existing values already highlighted so that the user will be able to add or remove items.

```
  For x = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    For Each ItemIndex In lbFA.?????
      If lbFA.ItemData(ItemIndex) = rs!FunctionalArea Then
        lbFA.Selected(ItemIndex) = True
      End If
    Next y
  Next x
```

What goes in the `lbFA.?????` area?  I think that's the only part I missing.

Comment: you can perform a standard for loop for ItemIndex = 0 to lbFA.listCount -1. This way you can get values from different column too if in case multi column listbox > lbfa.column(col_id, ItemIndex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can perform a standard for loop `for ItemIndex = 0 to lbFA.listCount -1`. This way you can get values from different column too if in case multi column listbox > lbfa.column(col_id, ItemIndex)

Comment: Got it!  Thanks...regular For Loop, not For Each.